# Add items to drop-down list Word 2010

Tags: vba, ms-word

I created a document and added a drop-down list content control in Microsoft Word 2010. How would I select this object and add items to it via VBA? An exhaustive search has led to being able to add one and add items, but I want to know how to add items to a list already on the document.

Also, is it possible to change the extension of a Microsoft Word 2010 document to (.zip) and add in an XML file. This XML file would house all the items to be added to the drop-down content control.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: @bibadia: Current, there was no specific code that I used. I tried to use the examples from MSDN and TechNet but none worked as those examples all required me to add a new drop-down content control to the document. What I would like to is pre-make my form and load all items into a drop-down content control when a document opens.

Comment: With Word VBA you can often learn *something* by looking at the relevant objects in the View->Object browser pane in the VB Editor and in many cases (but by no means all) recording a macro will give you some clues (in this case, recording the action of inserting some list items manually will give you a pointer, but probably not the most appropriate code.

Comment: @bibadia: I have tried to record the macro into VBA but once I hit the record button I cannot click on a drop-down content control. I can add one and add items to it but not select a drop-down content control that is already on the document.

Comment: If you select one first, then record the macro, you get information. Butit won't tell you how to specify a particular control to work with in code - so for that, you would typically go and look at the object model to see for example which objects have a ContentControls collection property, and how to identify a control within that collection.

Comment: @TroyPilewski Did you try my solution?

Comment: @AlexButenko: I did. This is what I type in the Visual Basic for Applications ThisDocument module. 'Option Explicit

Sub Document_Open()

Dim item As ContentControl

For Each item In Selection.Document.ContentControls
    If item.Title = "Unit Selection" Then
        item.DropdownListEntries.Add Text:="Item1", Value:="Item1"
        item.DropdownListEntries.Add Text:="Item2", Value:="Item2"
        item.DropdownListEntries.Add Text:="Item3", Value:="Item3"
    End If
Next

End Sub' Although, it did not work. I can send you the document...

Comment: I checked your code, works for me. I made a docm document with dropdownlist, set it's title "Unit Selection", put your code into ThisDocument of the document and reopened - and found all the items on the place.

Comment: @AlexButenko: Thank you. It may have worked. I may have another issue on my hands then. It seems as though I can't get macros enabled which may be causing it to not work on my end. I do have another question: Which I edited and added above earlier, can you add an XML document to the inside a docm file and have the item inserted from that XML file?

Comment: I have an answer for your additional question, but it's not really related to the first one. So I would recommend you to made another question.

Comment: @AlexButenko: I will mark this question as answered and start another. Thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101346/discussion-between-troypilewski-and-alex-butenko).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
For Each item In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
    If item.Title = "DropDown1" Then
        item.DropdownListEntries.Add Text:="Item1", Value:="Item1"
        item.DropdownListEntries.Add Text:="Item2", Value:="Item2"
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

You can find it by title or tag. Or by type - if it is only one dropdown in the document.